# Hide Android-PullToRefresh along with Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

I have three tabs and hiding the Action Bar on the middle tab. The third tab had pull to refresh. Android does a great job of animating the sliding in and out of the Action Bar but when I pull to refresh on the third tab and switch to the middle tab (where the Action Bar is hidden) I see the following:

[image: Pulling to refresh]

[image: Refreshing bar still overlaid when action bar hidden]

The action bar is hidden from the PageAdapter and hidden as follows:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        mActionBar.hide();
    } else {
        mActionBar.show();
    }
}
```

Pull to Refresh is implemented in a fragment (third tab) with the layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_canvas_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
    android:id="@+id/list_feed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

and initialised in the OnCreateView as follows:

```
mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
    .allChildrenArePullable()
    .useViewDelegate(StickyListHeadersListView.class, new ViewDelegate() {
        @Override
        public boolean isReadyForPull(View view, float v, float v2) {
        View childView = updatesListView.getChildAt(0);
        int top = (childView == null) ? 0 : childView.getTop();
        return top >= 0;
        }
    })
    .listener(this)
    .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No sorry, just hid the blue progress bar when the tab is switched